# Laptop (Lenovo z500) won't turn on if RAM is not taken out and put back in

Tags: laptop, memory, power-supply, battery, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo Z500 laptop (2013 model, i3-3120m, 4GB, Nvidia 740m).
it was working fine a few month ago, but after a few weeks without turning it on a problem has appeared.

When I turn it on the fan kicks in, the screen is black, battery and AC indicators are on. Then after 3-4 seconds it turns off, tries to restart, and the same thing happens. And it's just an infinite loop.
If I remove RAM and place it back in, the laptop successfully starts until I turn it off.

Side note: Previously, the laptop wasn't able to start up from battery, it needed to be turned on with charger plugged in and then it can be removed to work on battery.

What I tried:

- Replacing RAM with another stick (it previously had 2 of them, both 4 GB). I tried turning it on with both of them and then one by one (also tried changing the slots they were placed in). Nothing changed.
- Taking the battery off, holding power button for 15 seconds, turning it on with charger only. Put the battery back, try to boot again. Still nothing.

What could it be?

Comment: Looking at the whole picture, you have serious hardware problems, the mainboard may need replacement. But before thinking about that, update UEFI to the latest version.

Comment: @MichaelBay I updated BIOS when I just bought laptop (4 years ago), not sure that there is any new version, but I'll try it anyway, thanks.

Comment: Your PC has UEFI, not BIOS. It may sound as nitpicking but really isn't. Both have the same purpose but similarities end there. Of course, in deference to the less literate, many vendors keep calling it BIOS but it doesn't make it so. Think of it as the difference between an horse carriage and a modern sedan.